# Scriptural references for Anagha Lakshmi killing Jambasura

Tags: asuras, lakshmi

I have heard that Anagha Lakshmi, the wife of Dattatreya, killed the demon Jambasura.
Even Lakshmi is called as 'Jambasura ni barhini' in her Sahasranama.
Is there any scriptural references of the whole story?